# Centos 6 PHP OCI8 extention is not working (Undefined function oci_connect())

Tags: php, oracle, centos6, oci8

I am using Centos 6 64 bit OS. Recently i have installed OCI8 extension with php. After making all configuration i tried to execute the function oci_connect to connect with a Oracle Database remotely.

Unfortunately i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5
```

**I have installed oci8 like this:**

> OCI8
>
> Download the OCI8 source using pear
>
> ```
> $ pear download pecl/oci8
> $ tar -xvf oci8-1.4.9.tgz
> $ cd oci8-1.4.9
> ```
>
> Build and install the extension.
>
> ```
> $ phpize 
> $ ./configure --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib 
> $ make 
> $ sudo make install
> ```
>
> To enable the extension, add a file named oci8.ini in /etc/php.d with
>   this content:
>
> ```
> extension=oci8.so
> ```
>
> Validate that it was successfully installed.
>
> $ php -i | grep oci8
>
> You should see something like this:
>
> ```
> /etc/php.d/oci8.ini,
>
> oci8
> oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
> oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
> oci8.events => Off => Off
> oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
> oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
> oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
> oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
> oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
> oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
> ```

Ref: http://shiki.me/blog/installing-pdo_oci-and-oci8-php-extensions-on-centos-6-4-64bit/

I would like to mention that when the installation started is message was display something like: instantclient, /../../ to PUT THE PATH. I didn't give anything, just pressed enter. Is it the issue that i can't connect to Oracle ?

Need your help badly.

Thanks

Comment: i have done it the problem is solved now.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post the solution so others can fix it too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve problem. Actually the problem was the the environment library was not loaded. so i have loaded the environment of oracle manually via PHP .

Here is my code:

```
>     if (!$conn):
>                     /// INCLUDING ORACLE_HOME MANUALLY
>                             putenv("ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/");
>                            // INCLUDING LD_LIBRARY_PATH MANUALLY
>                             putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib");
> 
>                             $conn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT = 1521))) 
> (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = data)))";
>                             $conn = oci_pconnect("username", "password", $conn);
>                             endif;
>                             if($conn):
>                                 return $conn;
>                             endif;  
>                             if(!$conn):
>                                 redirect('login');
>                             endif;
>             }
```

Hope that it will help everyone

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**step-01** For correct installation oci8 refer this link

http://www.techinfobest.com/install-oci8/

After successfully installation

**step-02** Check php configuration where separate section for OCI8 listed are not

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

[image]

if not listed.

**step-03** check your httpd error log by terminal

```
cat /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

find any php error occured while after httpd service starting like

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

then it is the problem in your selinux permission. find below link to proper permission.

**step-03** http://www.cdatazone.org/index.php?/archives/37-PHP,-Oracle-and-SELinux.html

I have followed these steps and got success to oracle installation

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 7, I do not know if works in Centos 6.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf

// Add path to oracle client lib, the XX is the version, ex: /usr/lib/oracle/XX/client64/lib 

$ sudo ldconfig
$ sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Done!