# Oci_connect function is undefined in CentOS with Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, connection, centos7

oracle database connectivity issue in php with oci_connect function is undefined on linux centOs 7
follows this article too.
[Centos 6 PHP OCI8 extention is not working (Undefined function oci_connect())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731201/centos-6-php-oci8-extention-is-not-working-undefined-function-oci-connect)

Not found perfect solution for this.

Comment: You will need to provide some more information as to why the solutions proposed in that topic do not work for you

Comment: did you have enabled OCI libs in your PHP config?

Comment: Check `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 2):

You need install [OCI8] extension in php.ini:

Install both RPM packages:

```
rpm -ivh instantclient-basic-linux.XXX.rpm
rpm -ivh instantclient-sdk-linux.XXX.rpm
```

Install some prerequisite:

```
yum install php-pear
yum install php-devel
```

Download the OCI8 extension:

```
pear download pecl/oci8
tar xvzf oci8-1.4.7.tgz
cd oci8-1.4.7/
phpize
```

Configure the extension with your Oracle client library path (change the path …/11.2/… with your own version):

```
./configure --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
```

Compile and install:

```
make
make install
```

Now enable extension in php.ini

```
cd /etc/php.ini
```

And do to the following line:

```
[OCI8]
```

and enable extension:

```
;extension=oci8.so
```

to

```
extension=oci8.so
```

And restart server service:

```
service apache2 restart
```

or

```
service httpd restart
```

You have oci_connect () defined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ihojose I will try and let you know.

Comment: @ihojose I am facing the same error but I am using rhel 7.9. These instructions will work for me? please look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360325/no-releases-available-for-package-pecl-php-net-oci8