# After installing and enabling oci8 I get Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, apache, centos, oracle-call-interface, undefined-function

I have installed oci8 in my server. Enabled the extension in php.ini. When I run `php --ri oci8` I get

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php.ini on line 737 in Unknown on line 0

oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled
OCI8 Version => 2.0.8
Revision => $Id: f04114d4d67cffea4cdc2ed3b7f0229c2caa5016 $
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 12.2.0.1.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 12.2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
oci8.events => Off => Off

Statistics =>
Active Persistent Connections => 0
Active Connections => 0
```

When I run php --rf oci_connect

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php.ini on line 737 in Unknown on line 0
Function [ <internal:oci8> function oci_connect ] {

  - Parameters [5] {
    Parameter #0 [ <required> $username ]
    Parameter #1 [ <required> $password ]
    Parameter #2 [ <optional> $connection_string ]
    Parameter #3 [ <optional> $character_set ]
    Parameter #4 [ <optional> $session_mode ]
  }
}
```

But when I try to run my application I get **Call to undefined function oci_connect()**

Comment: Are you running your application through CLI or through a web interface - they will most likely have different php.ini files.

Comment: through browser

Comment: Set up a page with `phpinfo();` and check what that says(through the broswer) - also it should say what php.ini it is using.

Comment: chrome browser to be exact.

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path - /etc
I have changed the correct php.ini file

Comment: Don't forget to add oracle librabry to your server envvars

Comment: @Med can kindly elaborate on your answer

Comment: I don't know what oracle libraries and server envvars are you taking about?

Comment: If you are using apache, in [apachedir]/bin/envvars, there is a variable environnement called LIBPATH and you have to add the path to your oracle lib here

Comment: I dont have any apache folder, I have httpd folder and there are no envvars folder there

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you more. I can only help for apache webserver

Comment: @Med httpd and apache webserver are the same. On RedHat variants, such as CentOS and Fedora, apache webserver package is named as `httpd`. More info on envvars on RedHat variants is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/750155/where-to-find-the-environmental-variables-file-in-centos)

Comment: there is not bin folder in the httpd folder. There is only "conf, conf.d, logs, modules, run"

Comment: `bin` folder for `httpd` is not there in RedHat variants. For you to set an environment variable, you either add it at `/etc/profile` for global or `~/.bash_profile` for local environment. In redhat variants the binary is at `/usr/sbin/httpd.event` (generally)

Comment: You can also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157196/oci-connect-function-is-undefined-in-centos-with-oracle , that might help you.

Comment: @Cemal, I have done exactly what the link has told me and still it is giving me error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: when I try to see the page from the browser it says -> Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165886/discussion-between-cemal-and-eddard-stark).

Comment: @Cemal, because of internet connection i couldn't join

Comment: @Cemal can you please join now?

Comment: are you going to join?

Comment: The common guess is that you need to edit /etc/sysconfig/httpd and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the location of the Oracle client library directory.  Note the syntax to use varies with Apache versions.  You may need variables like ORACLE_HOME if you are NOT using Oracle Instant Client.   FWIW see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html