# No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/oci8"

Tags: php, rhel7, oci8, oraclelinux

I tried to install oci8-2.0.12 version for my PHP project but I am getting errors like
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/oci8".My project configuration details are below

Linux RHEL 7.9
PHP version - 5.4
oracle instaclient - 19.11

I tried 'pecl install oci8-2.0.12' no luck :-( also downloaded oci8-2.0.12.tgz and tried to install from there but failed. Please help. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I managed to install oci8 [php-pecl-oci8-2.0.12-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64.rpm] in rhel 7 and added extension=oci8.so , extension_dir='path to oci8.ini' but still phpinfo() doesn't show oci8 package. Also, I installed oracle instaclient 19.11 on my Linux server. Still, I am getting oci_connect(): Call to undefined function. Do I need to set a path variable? or what do I need to do? please guide

**Installed packages**

```
    php-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-ldap-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-pecl-oci8-2.0.12-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64 
    php-cli-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-gd-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-pear-1.9.4-22.el7.noarch 
    php-odbc-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-common-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-xml-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-pdo-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-process-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 
    php-mbstring-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: You need to give details.  Show the exacts commands run, and the errors. (Don't use screenshots).

Comment: Christopher, I managed to install [php-pecl-oci8-2.0.12-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64.rpm but still I am getting oci_connect(): call to undefined function. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ChristopherJones I installed this package php-pecl-oci8-2.0.12-1.el7.remi.5.4.x86_64.rpm but still I am getting error Call to undefined function. My question is this package will work with my existing packages? or can you please tell me which package will work? I posted full lists of installed packages in my question. Please look

Comment: How did you install Instant Client?  If you used ZIPs, did you run `ldconfig `to set the library path to the Oracle Instant Client?  Instructions are on the Instant Client download page.